# Need to convert a specific text format to date format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an export from Active Directory of user accounts in a .csv/Excel where the date created cell is of General format (text?) as follows:
`20150903075605.0Z` in cell `A1` which I need to convert to Date format as `MM/DD/YYYY`. I believe the text translates into `2015/09/03` but I could be wrong.

What I have tried so far:

1. Remove the `.0Z` and it changes to `2.01509E+ 13`. Then in the
   neighboring cell (`B1`) I try `=DATE(A1)` which gives me a `#VALUE`
2. Tried `=DATE(LEFT(C2,2)+100,MID(C2,3,2),RIGHT(C2,2))` but that gives me
   an obscure date of `4/12/2020`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula coverts the value in A1 into a true number:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))
```

You should apply number formatting to the cells where the formula is used. The number formatting would be: `mm/dd/yyyy`. In Excel, number formatting is often the best way to deal with dates.

If you need text instead of a true date, then:

```
=MID(A1,5,2)&"/"&MID(A1,7,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1,4)
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I did not refresh my stackoverflow session and did not see this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

let's say that `20150903075605.0Z` is contained in cell `A1`, then you can get the MM/DD/YYYY date format by the following concatenation:

```
mid(A1, 5, 2) & "/" & mid(A1, 7, 2) & "/" & left(A1, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I did not refresh my stackoverflow session and did not see this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did to fix this. First strip the .0Z out.

Cell A2: 20040330191012 converting this to date (MM/DD/YYYY) in B2 by typing in =DATE(MID(C2,1,4),MID(C2,5,2),MID(C2,7,2)) gives me 3/30/2004.

I am pretty sure this is correct but if one of you guru's can confirm, it would be deeply appreciated.